# Release Management xcopy deployer failing with JSON error

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

The Xcopy deployment method is constantly failing. Here is the error message.

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Environment 
TFS 2015 Update 1 (14.0.24712.0) 
RM on the same server as TFS

I am able to get the other tasks like DB backup, File deletion etc working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found another question with the same problem


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603767/failed-to-deploy-component-cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved after we switched from Server to UNC path for artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the shotgun approach to answering the issue. I've gotten it for a couple different reasons.

The times I've run into this error have usually been around the deployer not having access to the files.

- Make sure that the correct delivery method is set for the server/agent (e.g. Direct UNC access or Delivery over HTTP(s) through Release Management)
- Make sure the artifact exists (UNC or Server) and that it is looking for the correct one. Microsoft has stated that there is a regression in the latest release if you have more than one artifact from a TFS build. (Had to get a new .dll from them to fix the problem)
- Make sure the correct permissions are in place to give it access

I also had this occur when I had a component that had an encrypted variable and the action/tool behind it did not. I ended up removing all of my encrypted variables.

Comment: The server is configured for HTTP and I can access the artifact. Going by the error message on JSON, I am not sure if the problem is with the access.

Comment: Like I said, those were the issues that I found when I've encountered this exact error message in the past.

Comment: Okay. I am not sure how to get that dll. I don't have multiple drops but I have multiple projects in the solution. I don't know if that makes any difference. Thank you